# LowLevelKeyboardHook C

Tags: c, winapi

I try to write a litte hook programm in c.
The programm don't work and I don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if(nCode >= 0)
    {
        char key;
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
        key = (char)pKeyBoard->vkCode;
        printf("%c\n",key);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void) {
    HINSTANCE instance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, instance, 0);
    getchar();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    printf("ready");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I think the mistake is somewhere at the SetWindowsHookEx function.
When I start it, it only delays keyboardinputs for some seconds and it don't call the function LowLevelKeyboardProc.

What is wrong in the code?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please explain what does not work exactly.

Comment: This hook requires that you pump a message loop instead of calling getchar().

Comment: as far as i remember you have to split your code into a dll that contains the hook code and a programm that injects this dll into running processes.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch - not for WH_KEYBOARD_LL, IIRC.

Comment: 1) The use of `HINSTANCE` is wrong; Windows doesn't care you've loaded user32.dll, and the `HINSTANCE` needed is the `HINSTANCE` of your Windows application itself (which uses [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and receives an `HINSTANCE` automatically as the first parameter). 2) You don't check the return value of the call to `SetWindowsHookEx` to see if it succeeded or not; you're just assuming that it does. Read the documentation to find out what it returns and what you should do if it fails to find out why.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx), it says:

> **This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it.** The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**
>
> ...
>
> ... However, **the WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook is not injected into another process**. Instead, the context switches back to the process that installed the hook and it is called in its original context. Then the context switches back to the application that generated the event.

Your code does not have a message loop to receive the hook's messages.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
        char key = (char) pKeyBoard->vkCode;
        printf("%c\n", key);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(void)
{
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (!hook)
    {
        printf("error setting hook: %u", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);

    printf("ready");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure you're right. According to usage of `getchar()` and other "easy-win" functions, we're talking about a "console windows app". The console AFAIK is simulated via the standard windows messaging subsystem, and actually `getchar()` is no less than a message loop that terminates upon a formatted char arrival.

Comment: Thanks, now I'll try to understand it 100%. I've never seen this GetMessage loop before.

Comment: @valdo: The fact that `main()` is used means this is a console app. But a console app does not have its own message queue or message loop by default, you have to code for it yourself.  The console app is a separate process than the console itself. The console window process handles UI messages for the console and then forwards the input to running console app processes as needed.